# Cannot connect to data network after using Tor VPN (Orbot) on Android

Tags: android, vpn, orbot

When I disconnect from OrbotVPN on my phone while connected to data network, internet connection stops working on all applications except whatsapp.
Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings/More/Mobile Network/Access Point Name 
Tap on selected apn, make sure that proxy and port field are empty. 
[image]
If it doesn't work configure your Internet setting again, from your service provider.